# Linkage Error occured while executing the application in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, pom.xml

I googled about the problem I have then I applied all the given solutions but unluckily I'm still getting the same error (linkage error) while I execute my application. I also posted some part of pom.xml below that is related to the problem

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Error message:

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory; used in the signature
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:673)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4600)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's glassfish implementation of el.

Tomcat comes with `el-api.jar` and `jasper-el.jar` (it's own implementation) in `lib` directory. So you don't need that dependency whatsoever.

Also:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is not needed too. The sun reference implementation is not provided (as said, Tomcat comes with it's own implementation).

Also, JEE7 is not provided with Tomcat. So, having the following dependency (in provided scope) is wrong:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You should remove those three dependencies. The first one is the cause for the exception.